# White Screen in WKWebView in iOS11

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I use WKWebView in my app. There are two page, page A and Page B. Page B is the child page of page A. After I go into page B, I click back button to return Page A. Page A will become white. And then I scroll Page A, white screen will be gone.
[image]

Comment: Show your code, what you've tried so far.

Comment: I use `goToBackForwardListItem:`to return. I have checked url and title of webview. they are not nil. I have also checked UI hierarchy. it is not different. It seems like everything is ok except color. I can click items as usual, though I can not see it. @ImadAli